# =QUERY get column name and give column range in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two questions regarding the following code:

```
=QUERY({'Programs'!1:999},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19 where Col20 ='x' ")
```

1: Is there a way to say Col1 until Col19 (range) to tidy up the code?

2: Is there a way to say `where 'Book 1' ='x' ")` (where 'Book 1' is the first row column name) instead of `where Col20 ='x' ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, try the following trick:

```
=QUERY({Programs!1:999},"Select Col"&TEXTJOIN(",Col",,SEQUENCE(19))&" where Col20 = 'x'")
```

About the 2nd question, you could try to include `MATCH()`:

```
=QUERY({Programs!1:999},"Select Col"&TEXTJOIN(",Col",,SEQUENCE(19))&" where Col"&MATCH("Book1",Programs!1:1,0)&" = 'x'")
```

Comment: Thnx! Is it also possible to give it a range for question 1? Let's say 10-20.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes you can use `SEQUENCE(10,1,10)` meaning you aks for a sequence of 10, returnen in just a single column (irrelevant really), and start from 10 onwards.